# App crashed while trying to signin using cutom authentication in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, signing

I got to know i havent initiated the textlayout usr=findViewById(R.id.username); pass=findViewById(R.id.usrPass); but now i have added them and got error again. I am able to check if user exits or not but unable to verify the pass.As i click sign in with wrong pass the app crash as well as with the wright passs it crash.

**JAVA**

```
public class login extends AppCompatActivity {

TextInputLayout usr,pass;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    usr=findViewById(R.id.username);
    pass=findViewById(R.id.usrPass);
}
  public void loginUser(View view)
{
    if(!validateusrName()|!validatepass())
    {return;}
    else {
        isUser();
    }
}

private void isUser(){
    final String userEnteredusrname = usr.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
    final String userEnteredpass = pass.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();

    DatabaseReference reference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
    Query checkUser = reference.orderByChild("usrname").equalTo(userEnteredusrname);
    checkUser.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                usr.setError(null);
                usr.setErrorEnabled(false);
                String passfrmdb=dataSnapshot.child(userEnteredusrname).child("pass").getValue(String.class);
                if(passfrmdb.equals(userEnteredpass)){
                    usr.setError(null);
                    usr.setErrorEnabled(false);
                    String dbcllg=dataSnapshot.child(userEnteredusrname).child("cllg").getValue(String.class);
                    String dbemail=dataSnapshot.child(userEnteredusrname).child("email").getValue(String.class);
                    String dbname=dataSnapshot.child(userEnteredusrname).child("name").getValue(String.class);
                    String dbphno=dataSnapshot.child(userEnteredusrname).child("phno").getValue(String.class);
                    String dbusrname=dataSnapshot.child(userEnteredusrname).child("usrname").getValue(String.class);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("name",dbname);
                    intent.putExtra("usrname",dbusrname);
                    intent.putExtra("email",dbemail);
                    intent.putExtra("phno",dbphno);
                    intent.putExtra("cllg",dbcllg);

                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else{
                    pass.setError("Wrong Password");
                    pass.requestFocus();
                }
            }

            else {
                usr.setError("NO SUCH USER FOUND");
                usr.requestFocus();
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


}
}
```

**LOG**

```
2020-04-20 01:36:27.776 11545-11545/com.studenthelper.bscithelp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.studenthelper.bscithelp, PID: 11545
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
    at com.studenthelper.bscithelp.login$1.onDataChange(login.java:82)
    at com.google.firebase.database.Query$1.onDataChange(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:179)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:75)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:63)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:55)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Answer (score 1):

You got:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at com.studenthelper.bscithelp.login$1.onDataChange(login.java:82)
```

You got a `NullPointerException` while trying to compare two strings using `.equals()` method within `onDataChange()` in line 82.

Typically in `if(passfrmdb.equals(userEnteredpass)){` condition. where your `passfrmdb` is null.

So, the `passfrmdb` gets a null value by below expression:

```
String passfrmdb = dataSnapshot.child(userEnteredusrname).child("pass").getValue(String.class);
```

So, you need to check if this child "pass" already exist, and also the `userEnteredusrname` node already there. Here you need to start debugging

Answer (score 0):

You are getting null value for `passfrmdb` and you use it here as,

`if(passfrmdb.equals(userEnteredpass))`

You can not call `equals()` on null string.

Check your query for fetching password from DB, it it is correct or not.